# How to find out different cells from two excelsheets with the same format

Tags: excel

I have two excel files, each has 1553 rows and 40 columns. They have the same column names and should be identical. But it appears that there are some differences. I am wondering if there are some codes that can detect and highlight/summarize (which row/column) the different cells.

Comment: @lll - edit your question, so that question can be answered. I have a solution that may fulfill your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

- You can use IF formula like `IF(cell1=cell2,"","Not Matching")`
- You can also use conditional formatting to match two ranges and color differently: Select 1st range and go to Conditional formatting -> New Rules -> Format only cells that contain and select "Cell value" and "Not equal to" ->then select the starting cell of the next range in another worksheet (Note: Please remove referencing i.e. $ from the cell) and fill with any color for non matching value.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has an add-in for comparing files called "Inquire". Might be worth checking out. Note that there are version requirements.

Description of features:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-can-do-with-Spreadsheet-Inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42

How to turn it on:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-the-Inquire-add-in-6bc668e2-f3c6-4729-8ce1-75ea20aa9d90

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this code to find mismatched cells and highlight each for you. You need to change Sheet1 and Sheet2 with the appropriate sheet names and then make sure the row and column counts start and end with the right numbers. Hope that helps!

```
Sub comparison()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim CellValuews1 As Variant
Dim CellValuews2 As Variant
Dim ErrorCount As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
ErrorCount = 0

For I = 1 To 40
    For X = 1 To 1553
        CellValuews1 = ws1.Cells(X, I).Value
        CellValuews2 = ws2.Cells(X, I).Value

        If CellValuews1 = CellValuews2 Then
        Else
            ws1.Cells(X, I).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ws2.Cells(X, I).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1

        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox "There were " & ErrorCount & " Cells that didn't match. These are now highlighted yellow"

End Sub
```